# How can I fix a single radiator that is not providing heat?

Tags: central-heating

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is my radiator not getting hot water or have air in it?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3280/why-is-my-radiator-not-getting-hot-water-or-have-air-in-it)

All of my radiators are working, apart from one. There is heat in the pipe attached to it , but the radiator is cold. I have bled it several times , but all that is happening is that I am continually filling buckets of water.

Comment: Steam or forced hot water?